# jQuery process JSON string from variable withou making AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make jQuery to process JSON string from variable without making AJAX call because this JSON string will be generated from JSON2HTML, but `jQuery.getJSON` require to make AJAX call which is waste of resource. Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this problem?

JSON string which had been generate from JSON2HTML.

```
[{"tag":"div","id":"0","class":"sgph","children":[
      {"tag":"div","data-scoretype":"","class":"sgi","id":"1","children":[
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"up","html":"up"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"down","html":"down"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"edit","html":"change"},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"del","html":"delete"}
        ]},
      {"tag":"div","class":"scph","children":[
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"score_type","class":"add","html":"score type"}
        ]},
      {"tag":"div","class":"stph","children":[
          {"tag":"div","class":"sti","id":"1","children":[
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"up","html":"up"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"down","html":"down"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"edit","html":"change"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"del","html":"delete"}
            ]},
          {"tag":"div","class":"sti","id":"3","children":[
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"up","html":"up"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"down","html":"down"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"edit","html":"change"},
              {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"del","html":"delete"}
            ]},
          {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_topics","class":"add","html":"add topic"}
        ]}
    ]},
      {"tag":"div","id":"1","class":"sgph","children":[
      {"tag":"button","data-btnrole":"satis_group","class":"add","html":"add group"}
    ]}
]
```

jQuery code that I did.

```
//json_str will store JSON string which had been generate from JSON2HTML.
var json_str=$.parseJSON(FormatJSON(toTransform($('div.satis_form').children()))); 
$.getJSON(json_str, function(data){
    $.each(data,function(i,val){
        if(val.tag == 'button'){
            delete val[i];
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Why doing `$.getJSON` if the JSON object is already there in `json_str`...?? If `json_str` is a string just parse it with either `JSON.parse(string)`(Pure JS) or `$.parseJSON(string)`(jQuery).

Comment: @Xlander Seems like my brain gone wild and didn't noticed that it doesn't need `$.getJSON` at all, and thanks by the way.

Comment: It's ok, it's by doing errors that we learn. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be like this since `json_str` is JSON object.

```
var json_str=$.parseJSON(FormatJSON(toTransform($('div.satis_form').children()))); 
    $.each(data,function(i,val){
        if(val.tag == 'button'){
            delete val[i];
    }
})
```